# errors with MakeUppercase and Beamer's insertsectionhead

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to use `\MakeUppercase` on `\insertsectionhead` of the `beamer` class:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \MakeUppercase{\insertsectionhead}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this example produces an endless series of errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Try substituting `{\MakeUppercase\protect\insertsectionhead}` for `\MakeUppercase{\insertsectionhead}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This eliminates the errors, but the sectiontext is still not uppercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to expand `\insertsectionhead` before applying `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\insertsectionHEAD}{%
  \expandafter\insertsectionHEADaux\insertsectionhead}
\newcommand{\insertsectionHEADaux}[3]{#1{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

\insertsectionHEAD

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In your case `\insertsectionhead` expands to

```
\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{Section 1}
```

so we add before it `\insertsectionHEADaux` that gets `\hyperlink` as argument `#1`, `Navigation\the\c@page` as `#2` and `Section 1` as `#3`, and eventually

```
\hyperlink{Navigation \the\c@page}{\MakeUppercase{Section 1}}
```

is executed. In this way the link name is not uppercased.

---

A different solution is patching the commands responsible for defining `\insertsectionhead`; this might be better, because it doesn't require different commands in the document.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}
  {\def\insertsectionhead{#2}}
  {\def\insertsectionhead{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@section}
  {\def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}}
  {\def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

\insertsectionhead

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Benjamin You're welcome. I added a different solution.

Comment: Do you know why your first solution won't work with \insertframetitle? IOW, replace line 4 with `\expandafter\insertsectionHEADaux\insertframetitle}` and you get many errors. I tried a few combinations of `\protect` and `[fragile]`, but no luck. TIA!

Comment: @Leo That probably warrants a different question

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149231

Comment: This also works if you're trying to override the color of \insertsectionhead.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \MakeUppercase{\expandafter\protect\insertsectionhead}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Just a little expansion control. Please note that this does tweak the appearance of the current `\insertsection`, the stored string it self is still lowercase. And it may break the pdf links.

[image]