# Uppercase Frame Titles

Tags: beamer

I am trying to get the frame title to always be displayed uppercase. 
I found [errors with MakeUppercase and Beamer's insertsectionhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112526) helpful,
but the same command that worked with `\insertsectionhead`
did not work with `\insertframetitle`. IOW, this works (from the linked question):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\newcommand{\insertsectionHEAD}{%
\expandafter\insertsectionHEADaux%
    %\insertframetitle}
    \insertsectionhead}
\newcommand{\insertsectionHEADaux}[3]{#1{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

\insertsectionHEAD

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but exchanging the comment between lines 5 and 6 above causes compilation to fail.

I was able to get this second version to work:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
      \expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\insertframetitle
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks]
{Frame 1}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but if you uncomment the `[allowframebreaks]` in the frame declaration you also get errors. The `\tableofcontents` also causes problems in some more complex code I have, but I was unable to reproduce the error in these MWEs.

Comment: The last one works if you substitute `\MakeUppercase` with `\uppercase`

Comment: @karlkoeller I can verify that, including in my more complex case. Thanks. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `allowframebreaks` adds to `Frame 1` in `\insertframetitle` also `\usebeamertemplate` that's not legal in `\MakeUppercase`.

My opinion is that if you want an uppercase title you should simply type it uppercase. However, this might work.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{textcase,regexpatch}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \makeatletter
  \regexpatchcmd{\insertframetitle}
    {(\c{usebeamertemplate}.*)\c{fi}}
    {\c{NoCaseChange}\cB\{\1\cE\}\c{fi}}
    {}{}%
  \makeatother
  \MakeTextUppercase{\insertframetitle}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
{Frame 1}

\tableofcontents

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```