# Uppercase beamer frame titles containing math

Tags: beamer, math-mode, frame-title, textcase

I am trying to automate uppercase for frame titles in beamer in such a way that uppercase ignores all math-mode content in these titles. I have seen [Uppercase Frame Titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149231/uppercase-frame-titles), but the solution there fails to deal with math content correctly. In order to ignore math-mode for uppercase I tried to use the textcase package, but that has unexpected behavior with frame titles. Below is a minimal example that shows this unexpected behavior with `\insertframetitle`. The last line in the content of the frame is displayed as I would expect, but that line does not use `\insertframetitle`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
    \MakeUppercase{\insertframetitle} and \uppercase\insertframetitle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title $a = \sin(b)$}
\MakeUppercase\insertframetitle\\
\uppercase\insertframetitle\\
\MakeUppercase{Title $a = \sin(b)$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beamer is adding an extra set of `{..}` around the title (which is why you did not get a syntax error when using `\uppercase` with no brace group, however it is preventing MakeTextUppercase seeing the math.  So

[image]

So you can use the same implicitly added group as the argument delimiter for `\makeTextUppercase`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    {\expandafter\MakeTextUppercase\insertframetitle}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title $a = \sin(b)$}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```