# Possibility to exclude coloring certain links using hyperref

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I'm preparing a beamer presentation and there are certain links I do not want getting highlighted.

I've tried setting

```
colorlinks = false
```

inside the *hypersetup*, but naturally that disables coloring completely, while I actually want only internal links (*linkcolor*) to be disabled, while mantaining URL and cite colors, for instance.

I've also tried the following

```
linkcolor = myColor
```

before the parts I don't want highlighted, the problem is that since it is a beamer presentation, there is a sidebar showing the internal links in each frame, and so changing the link color continually changes the color of the titles in the sidebar.

Is there a way to just disable internal links coloring in the entire document, just as if *colorlinks* was set to false, but only affecting internal links and not the rest? (or possibly any other workaround).

**EDIT**: The problem was solved, turns out this can be explicitly stated just by configuring hyperref like so

```
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks,
   linkcolor=.
}
```

And so internal links will mantain its original color while the rest will keep highlighted. Here's a small working example showing this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=.
}

\title{Title name}
\author{Author name}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\frame{ Test URL: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/} }
\section{Section 2}
\frame{ This is another frame \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/} }

\end{document}
```

You can see on the sidebar the sections, which are internal hyperlinks, do not get highlighted, but the URL's do.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214090/18228

Comment: @HerrK. Absolutely, I'll edit my original post to explain the answer and post a MWE. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, Beamer automatically loads the `hyperref`package. So you don't need to load it again with `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: Oh, well that's good to know, I'll get rid of it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until a proper answer comes along, you might consider using this quick and dirty trick:

```
\hyperlink{some label}{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{link text}}
```

If you use it very often, then create a command for it:

```
\newcommand\myhlink[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{#2}}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\newcommand\myhlink[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
  \hyperlink{some label}{colored link text}

  \myhlink{some label}{uncolored link text}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=some label]{Target Frame}
  text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```