# {beamer} use \insertsection to load image gives error: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: beamer, includegraphics

I'm trying to set up a template for a section frame. 
On this frame I want to load an image selected by the section title as described in [this question](/questions/457093/beamer-use-insertsection-to-load-image-in-section-frame-replace-spaces#comment1149827_457093).

But when applying the suggested solution I get an endless loop.
The following MWE throws an error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\begin{document}
\section{some section name}
    \begin{frame}{\insertsectionhead}
          \insertsectionhead

% this line causes: 
% TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \section{some section name}
          \includegraphics[draft]{\insertsectionhead}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

how can I use the section name as file name in `\includegraphics{}` avoiding the endless loop?

Comment: off-topic: `graphicx` is loaded by `beamer`. why you not use solution in given link as it is?

Comment: @Zarko *"why you not use solution in given link as it is?"* The solution currently says to use the section number which also throws the "capacity exeeded" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing shamelessly from an [excellent answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112557/2417):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\newcommand\insertsectionHEAD{%
  \expandafter\insertsectionHEADaux\insertsectionhead}
\def\insertsectionHEADaux#1#2#3{#3}


\begin{document}
\section{some section name}
    \begin{frame}
          \includegraphics[draft]{\insertsectionHEAD}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Explanation to follow later, I have to go now...